# AWS:Allowing Access to an IAM application user to a specific S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I know this question has been posted and answered many times but none of the solution has worked for my situation.

Following is the policy attached to one of the IAM user that will be used by application to access a s3 bucket called xyz-billing:

```js
{  
    "Version": "2012-10-17",  
    "Statement": [  
    {  
      "Effect": "Allow",  
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],  
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::xyz-billing"]  
    },  
    {  
      "Effect": "Allow",  
      "Action": [  
        "s3:PutObject",  
        "s3:GetObject",  
        "s3:DeleteObject"  
      ],  
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::xyz-billing/*"]  
    }  
  ]  
}
```

In fact I have tried multiple ways of defining policy but below is the common issue in all:

- When I try to simullate policy everything is denied.
- When I use asterix for the "Resource" :"*" the simulator shows allowed.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This policy works for me when simulating it on my account. Are you sure that you don't have another policy that explicitely denies this user access to your S3 bucket(s)? Check the [evaluation logic](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html) of IAM policies for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the cpmment. The user and the bucket is newly created by me. In fact, I have tried with public buckets and other user but still it failed. no other policy is attached to either bucket or the user. I will have a look at evaluation logic.

Comment: evaluation of the policy looks like it should be able to access that bucket. No problem in that department

Comment: This policy looks ok. Make sure you don't have a bucket policy on the 'xyz-billing' bucket that is denying the user access.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the bucket itself had permissions restricting other users from viewing it which caused the issue. Take a look [at this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/EditingBucketPermissions.html) for editing your bucket permissions. You would need list,view permissions on the S3 bucket in order to allow your Lambda access the bucket (and ofcourse appropriate role, policy)